# Image encoding problem

Tags: opencv

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello

I have a cv::Mat of depth CV_8UC1 (that I know for sure it is this since it what the camera streams). In the camera driver I can do cv::imshow and display this CV_8UC1 image and I see it right:

[image: image description]

In order to send it as a ros message, I use the `sensor_msgs::image_encodings::MONO8` image encoding (I tryed with `sensor_msgs::image_encodings::TYPE_8UC1` and I can not see the image using image_view nor with rviz, but I made a simple subscriber that susbscribes to the image, undecodes using the same image encoding that I used in the publisher and the result is the same as using mono8 and being able to visualize it using image_view package) and I get this image:

[image: image description]

Which is clearly not right. I dont know what do I need to do to convert this cv::Mat CV_8UC1 to a proper mono8 image for ros. Any help?

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/238743/image-encoding-problem/) by [apalomer](https://answers.ros.org/users/1165/apalomer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 318 on 2016-07-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ok, Just for testing I did something that I though would not be smart. I used `sensor_msgs::image_encodings::RGB8` and now it works... Can somebody tell me why?

Thank you.

---

Originally posted by [apalomer](https://answers.ros.org/users/1165/apalomer/) with karma: 318 on 2016-07-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [random_enthusiast](https://answers.ros.org/users/57468/random_enthusiast/) on 2020-08-07**:
You can see my code, it's almost what you want to know. Right [here](https://github.com/Kanishk598/Ubuntu-and-ROS).